# Range-Based for loops in vs2012 rc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

The following range-based for loop works fine in VS2012:

```
int values[] = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i: values)
{
}
```

However, this one doesn't work:

```
for(int i: {1, 2, 3})
{
}
```

What's the difference?

P.S.: I cannot find the std::initializer_list template class either. I need to know what C++11 features this new VS2012 RC supports. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual C++ 2012 does not support initializer lists.

The best resource for which C++11 features are supported in Visual C++ 2012 is [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) on the Visual C++ blog.

Comment: WOW, that's embarrassing. Do you have any idea how long does it take to support the entire standard?

Comment: @MehdiAfzal Hard to say. At the current rate, we're looking at 2020-2030 or so. The  team has been saying that they intend to speed things up, but they *also* said that when 2010 was released, and then spent two years adding, well, next to nothing. So we'll have to wait and see. Sadly, they usually seem more interested in inventing new proprietary dialects of C++, than actually adding support for the C++ core language.

Comment: Nobody has full support yet, but give it time. GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html Clang: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html